# Isolate records that have multiple values (derived table)

Tags: ms-access, unique

Over simplified I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID - NAME - EMAIL
1 - JIM - Jim@hotmail.com
2 - JIM - Jim@gmail.com
3 - BARRY - Barry@hotmail.com
4 - JACK - Jack@hotmail.com
```

I would like to query this table and return only the fields for which NAME has multiple EMAIL values, so requied result is:

```
NAME - EMAIL
JIM - Jim@hotmail.com
JIM - Jim@gmail.com
```

The other two (Barry and Jack) would not need to be returned as they have only one value for email.

I am struggeling a bit with a derived table set-up in Access, the following will not work because it gives me an error in the FROM clause.. Is there another syntax?

```
select DISTINCT x.ID, x.NAME, x.EMAIL
from t as x
join (
    select ID
    from t
    group by ID
    having count(distinct EMAIL) > 1
) as y
    on x.ID = y.ID
```

Comment: Uh, what is the syntax error in the FROM clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Select z.Name, t.Email from (

SELECT t.Name
FROM t
GROUP BY t.Name
HAVING Count(t.[Name])>1

)  as z INNER JOIN t ON z.name=t.name
```

Comment: hi thanks, but this gives a syntax error as well... ('syntax error in join operation)

Comment: Hi, I hope you are using MS access. I have tested this and it works.

Comment: @BarrievanBoven Did you try?

Comment: @BarrievanBoven  As already mentioned it works. What's the exact error? Can you show error screenshot if error is true.

Comment: I cannot post a screenshot here, but the error reads "the microsoft access database engine cannot find the input table or query 't'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly. 

This error literally pops up when I use the query you propose. Could it be that we use a different version of Access? Otherwise I do not now why it does work for you.

Comment: That means the table name or query is incorrect. I have used the same fields and table name which you have posted in question.  Obviously they have to be updated if they differ in your database. It has nothing to do with access version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select x.ID, x.NAME, x.EMAIL
from t as x
where x.NAME in (
    select t.NAME
    from t
    group by t.NAME
    having count(*) > 1)
```